# Face feature extraction using matlab

Tags: matlab, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I'm looking for a way to do face feature extraction - eyes, noes, mouth  get the square containing and center location.

in case openCV is the better toolbox I'd appreciate some example / explanation of how to use it
thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I used two nice packages for this purpose:

1. A work by [Mark Everingham, Josef Sivic and Andrew Zisserman](http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~vgg/research/nface/)  - very simple and elegant.
2. A newer one by [X. Zhu and D. Ramanan](http://www.ics.uci.edu/~xzhu/face/).

Both methods come with code - a very non-trivial courtesy in the computer vision community.
So, if you are using their implementation - please give them positive feedback!

If you are only interested in detecting faces: that is, finding the bounding box aroundeach face in the image, OpenCV has implementation of Viola-Johns face detector (ans also LBP, if I'm not mistaken). These detectors should provide you with bounding boxes around faces very efficiently. Google the OpenCV docs for more information.

Comment: the first did not work for gray images. second I had some problems using. Any lib you know for gray images?

Comment: @user271077 - try replicate grey image as three channels with same value. Results would be sub optimal, but if it works for you...

Comment: -------- ignore previous comment,  first works excellent :) my mistake of testing

Comment: @user271077 - don't forget to give positive feedback to authors!